# Should I need to update file-descriptor here?

Tags: c, linux, file-descriptor

One file size of 2gb is being transmitting from server to client. On the client side, after receiving 512mb of that file, I open that with:

```
FILE *fp= fopen("that file","r");
```

Now after the download is complete, can I access the whole 2gb data of that file with that  file descriptor?  Or do I need to re-open it to access the whole file?

Comment: Why do you want to open the file before it is fully downloaded?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg i am just thinking if file is being streaming and i wish to play it while that then?!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should avoid spaces in Linux file names. So your example should be `FILE *fp= fopen("that_file","r");` having spaces (or even control characters like newline) in file names is bad taste.

And under Linux, a file descriptor (which is *not* a `FILE*` handle!) is a small integer, which is handled by the kernel: within the kernel, processes have a table of open files, and their application code refer (using system calls like `open` and `read` etc) to these files by their file descriptor. The standard C library manage buffering and file descriptors (so inside the `FILE` data structure there are buffers and a file descriptor).

So if you have one process reading a file, and another writing it at the same time (this is bad practice), the reading process is able to read all the available bytes.

So you don't need to "update" your `fp` but your code is crappy (because of lack of synchronization between reading & writing process).

Comment: 1> thnks for saying about spaces  2> what if i open that file using open() then shoud i need to update fp ?

Comment: No (but perhaps calling fsync could help, but I believe you don't need it). However, I do insist that it is *bad practice* since you should have some way of synchronizing the writer and the reader processes

Comment: @Mr.32: there's no difference here between `open` and `fopen`. There's no need to `fsync` either.

Comment: There is a huge difference between `open` & `fopen` : `open` is a system call (and you should buffer data, to avoid calling `write` on too small data chunks) returning an integer file descriptor. `fopen` is a standard C library function, returning a `FILE*` pointer. You'll use `fprintf` or `fwrite`  to write there, and it buffers for you. See also `fflush`.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch To be precise, most modern OSes will do read/write buffering for you, to some extent. The disk controllers will also do some buffering. Thus, while it is good practice to do some amount of buffering, it isn't *strictly* required.

Comment: I know that, but On Linux the overhead of each syscalls (microseconds) is large enough that buffering I/O is really needed (calling 1024 times the write(2) syscall for one byte each is much slower than doing a single `write` of 1024 bytes at once). Of course, the kernel itself is also buffering, and often most of the data stays in the kernel disk cache and don't hit the disk quickly.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch does same things also happen with fwrite ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to reopen the file; if you periodically request the file's size in the client, you'll see it grow. Note that the file doesn't grow until the writing process flushes its buffers.

(A `FILE*` is not a file descriptor, btw.)

Comment: a fsync might be in order (especially with fuse based implementations that are allowed to cache stat info locally IIRC)

Answer (score -2):

The file descriptor should be updated for accessing the whole file. Generally when a file is opened, the current contents of the file will be loaded in the memory and it will be refrenced by the file descriptor and any update on the file outside will not get updated in the loaded memory.

Comment: This is utter nonsense. Opening a file will *not* load it in memory.

Comment: `The fopen() function shall open the file whose pathname is the string pointed to by filename, and associates a stream with it.`